# Storing multiple cells from one row vs one cell and multiple contiguous rows in bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

What is the pros and cons in storing multiple cells in a single row key vs multiple rows each with one cell in bigtable?

For example is there benefit of storing

```
                       columnFamily1                        ColumnFamily2
                    col1         col2                    col1        col2

rowkey1+time1        v1           v2                      v3          v4
rowkey1+time2        v1           v2                      v3          v4
rowkey2+time2        v1           v2                      v3          v4
```

vs

```
                      columnFamily1                        ColumnFamily2
                    col1         col2                    col1        col2

rowkey1           time1:v0       time1:v1               time1:v2     time1:v3 
                  time2:v10      time2:v5               time2:v4     time2:v8 

rowkey2           time1:v0       time1:v1               time1:v2     time1:v3 
                  time2:v10      time2:v5               time2:v4     time2:v8
```

Comment: One of the cons of having a row key with timestamp is hotspotting. Check this [article](https://medium.com/@duhroach/cloud-bigtable-time-series-data-eecc32dd9cf2) for a detailed explanation and how to handle it to avoid hotspotting.

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series goes into details of different approaches but it depends on the data e.g. if your rowkey1, rowkey2 etc. have high cardinality , you may use timestamp in the rowkey as in your option without hotspotting.

You can also do a combination e.g. in your first example create time buckets. You can have 2022-01 (just year-month) in the rowkey then timestamps within that row or year-month-day, year-month-day-hour etc. depending on the granularity of your time series data. This would allow you to skip rows that don't have relevant data quickly and only look into rows that contain the data you're looking for.